# Retrieve code from PHP Bluemix Application

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

In my bluemix space I have a php application running.
I want to make some change to the code of this application.
But I don't have the code locally.

In my commandshell I can connect to my bluemix space with the Cloud Foundry command line interface.
If I use the command `cf apps`, I see the application.

Can anybody tell me how I retreive the code from this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Cloud Foundry CLI plugin](https://github.com/ibmjstart/cf-download), which allows you to download your application after it has staged.

I have been using it and it works like a charm.

Comment: That was the sollution.  Tx